# Can't deploy adapter/application in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

In a production installation over 'WAS_LIBERTY_CORE_V8.5.5.4' with 'DB2':
I have now a simple configuration in server.xml.

The mobilefirst console shows the runtimes but I can't deploy adapters or applications. This is the content of messages.log. This 2 lines appears every attempt to upload an adapter/application:

```
[19/04/15 19:19:37:667 CEST] 0000008e org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry    I The system cannot find any method in the com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService class that supports POST. Verify that a method exists.
[19/04/15 19:19:37:683 CEST] 0000008e org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             I The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (405) with message 'null' while processing POST request sent to http://MACHINENAME:9080/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/test/
```

More info:

```
wlp.install.dir = C:/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
java.version = 1.7.0_79
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.7.0_79-b15)
os = Windows Server 2008 R2 (6.1; amd64) (en_US)​
DB: DB2 in localhost
```

Complete server.xml file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAEyIioPI2YT2NPZXdCcktoT1U/view?usp=sharing

Complete console.log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAEyIioPI2YUDhLZDQ0Qmgydk0/view?usp=sharing

Complete messages.log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxAEyIioPI2YdUREcjcyd3JYNGs/view?usp=sharing

I'm tried with other Java version like 'SDK_JAVA_TE_V7.0_WASLC_V8.5.5', with other runtimes, reinstalling all...

Comment: Please provide the full log and not just 2 lines from it.

Comment: I edit me question with more info.

Comment: Does the error happen in all browsers? IE, Chrome, Firefox, ...

Comment: The error appears only in IE9! It works with Chrome! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, the error appears to happen only in IE 9.
As a work around, use a different browser such as Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc... in order to deploy artifacts.

The issue with IE 9 will be investigated.